# SWIG cannot convert typedef type correct

Tags: c++, python, arrays, typedef, swig

I'm using SWIT to convert a vc project to python.
I found when a struct has a member which type is like "typedef char TEXT[16]" cannot be converted correctly.
for example:

```
typedef char TEXT[16];
struct MYSTRUCT
{       
    TEXT    TradingDay;     
};
```

The wrapper cpp cannot compile all right. 
"error C2075: 'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces"
BUT,if typedef is not an array , like this:

```
    typedef int NUMBER;
    struct MYSTRUCT2
{       
    NUMBER Money;       
};
```

there will be all right.
what should I do?
thx!

P.S:
i file:

```
%module MyDataAPI
%include "typemaps.i"

%header %{
#include "../References/MyDataAPI.h"

%}

namespace MyDataAPI
{
     struct MYSTRUCT
    {       
        TEXT    TradingDay;     
    };
    struct MYSTRUCT2
    {       
        NUMBER Money;       
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `typedef` statements are processed by SWIG.  `%header` only adds code to the generated file, that data is not processed by SWIG.  `%inline` both adds the code directly to the generated file *and* processes it with SWIG. Here's my `.i` file:

```
%module x

%inline %{
    typedef char TEXT[16];
    typedef int NUMBER;
    namespace MyDataAPI
    {
        struct MYSTRUCT
        {
            TEXT TradingDay;
        };
        struct MYSTRUCT2
        {
            NUMBER Money;
        };
    }
%}
```

And use:

```
T:\>py
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import x
>>> a=x.MYSTRUCT()
>>> a.TradingDay
''
>>> a.TradingDay='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'   # Note this is too long, 17 chars...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'MYSTRUCT_TradingDay_set', argument 2 of type 'char [16]'
>>> a.TradingDay='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
>>> a.TradingDay
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
>>> b=x.MYSTRUCT2()
>>> b.Money
0
>>> b.Money=100
>>> b.Money
100
```